# What are the Electronic Components & Devices for
Digital Modulation Formats?

Tags: components, digital-communications, digital-modulation

So I have been searching on google for hours but I found nothing, I want to know **what are the Components and Devices for Digital Modulation Formats ?**
Our Professor asked us to write a report
The report title was this question ,
The Lecture : Electronic System
Any help or hint to find the answer to my question .

Comment: This is impossibly broad.  Start by considering who is asking the question and what their motivation is.  Narrow the scope of it to something specific; if it's an academic exercise the necessary answer will be what the person asking wants to hear, however artificial or assumption-directed that may unfortunately be (history of the class will be a clue as to what they want)

Comment: We generally don't don't do homework assignments.  Help with specific questions, yes.  But your post is overly broad.

Comment: @user287001 he just sent this title and asked us to do a report about it!

Answer (score 3):

Ever heard some names of digital modulation methods? such as "16APSK" ? Or more general names like amplitude, frequency and phase shift keying? You should also know where they are used and to achieve what. I guess you should find whole systems which use digital modulations, what devices in the systems can be purchased separately to perform something useful with digital modulations, what electronic components today in those devices do the work and some generally needed math operations in that work.

Do not expect you'll find a good ready to copy and paste text for this by making web searches for the given subject as your professor wrote it. If you find it with my help and copy&paste it your professor reveal in 10 seconds where it was taken from and gives to you a plain zero. The purpose of this task is to find soon those who haven't got what's needed in academic studies. The idea is to force the students to build an overall picture and generate an organized text of it. If you have got what this needs you'll quite soon laugh for this incident. If you haven't you will bang your head to wall again and again.

Comment: Thank you for answering.